# how text-underline-offset depends on text-underline-position: under?

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

While working on a project, I came across the fact that a text-underline-offset property works differently depending on the text-underline-position: under and I can’t understand why

that's what I mean

```
<p class="first">Paragraph</p>
<p class="second">Paragraph</p>
```

```
p{
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 10px;
}

.first{
  text-underline-position: under;
}
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SO72.png)

Answer (score 2):

To understand this, you have to understand what exactly `text-underline-position: under` really means.

In typography, there are some invisible lines that run through the text. For this example, you just need to understand the baseline and descender. The baseline is where the bottoms of most normal letters like 'A', 'h', and 'C' rest. The descender is where the bottoms of letters like 'p', 'y', and 'q' rest. Subscripts like the 8 in 'C<sub>8</sub>' align with the descender as well.

[image]

By default, when you use `text-decoration: underline`, the line is placed at the baseline. If you use `text-underline-position: under`, you're telling it to place the underline at the descender instead.

Therefore, when you use `text-underline-offset`, you're just adding offset to whatever position of the underline you set. Naturally, if the underline is at the baseline (default), `text-underline-offset: 10px` will create a smaller space than if the underline is at the descender.

Answer (score 0):

text-underline-offset allows us to set the offset distance of an underline line (-8px | 0 | 7px) while text-underline-position just allows us to set the specific position of the underline (auto | under). I hope these links help us to clear it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-position

Comment: This answer misses the point which is the difference between baseline and under the descenders positioning. The default being baseline.